# NoReverseMatch found in django for app homepage

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-url-reverse

I am trying to redirect an link from app to another page view function. But after pointing the page correctly I am getting NoReverseMatch Found error on apps main page which haves no connection to it.

This is urls.py of main Project
urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('teacher/', include('teacher.urls')),
    path('student/', include('student.urls')),
]
```

This is urls.py for respective app which is teacher
urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="index"),
    path(r'^detailed/(?P<reportid>\d{0,4})/$', views.detailed, name="detailed"),
]
```

I am also including views.py as error is pointing at view.py
views.py

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'teacher/report.html')
def detailed(request, reportid):
    weeklyr = wreport.objects.all()
    dailyr = dreport.objects.all()
    split = SplitOfWeek.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'teacher/detailed.html')
```

I have tried adding `r'^teacher/$'` at main urls.py and `r'^$'` at urls.py of teacher app but after adding it shows there is url found for teacher.

This is the detailed error message:
`Reverse for 'detailed' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['teacher/\\^detailed/\\(\\?P(?P<reportid>[^/]+)\\\\d\\{0,4\\}\\)/\\$$']`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use regexes with `path`

A simple fix would be to do:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="index"),
    path('detailed/<int:reportid>/', views.detailed, name="detailed"),
]
```

However this would allow any number for `reportid`. If you really to limit the length to four characters, then you could use the regex with `re_path`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="index"),
    re_path(r'^detailed/(?P<reportid>\d{1,4})/$', views.detailed, name="detailed"),
]
```

Another option would be to register a [custom path converter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#registering-custom-path-converters) for `reportid`.

Comment: using <int:reportid> isn't helping it creates same type of error `Reverse for 'detailed' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['teacher/detailed/(?P<reportid>[0-9]+)/$']
`

Comment: It is helping - your code that used a regex with `path()` was never going to work. Now you need to fix the next part of the error. *with no arguments not found* means that you aren't providing the report id when you call `reverse()` or use the `{% url %}` tag.

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand issue. I fixed it by giving a default value to function as `def detailed(request, reportid=None):` and creating a additional url for detailed page like `path('detailed/', views.detailed, name="detailed")`. If you would like you can update your question with this answer so I can accept. And upvote my question if you think this may be useful to others

Answer (score 0):

After help in understanding issue from @Alasdair i found that adding a default value for `reportid` in view function is solution.

so views.py changed to this

```
def detailed(request, reportid=None):
```

Also to go to that default value I added url for default view.

So urls.py changed to this

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="index"),
    path('detailed/<int:reportid>/', views.detailed, name="detailed"),
    path('detailed/', views.detailed, name="detailed"),
]
```